# What plane cost less per mile to operate for one person?

Tags: flight-training, aircraft-identification, range, accident-statistics

The 98 Toyota Corolla has a strong history for being a **low maintenance, fuel efficient** and **cheap** car. 400k mile reliability if driven with respect and preventative maintenance.

What plane has these qualities with at least a 450 mile range? So I can fly back and forth to flight school instead of driving.

I am sure there are many that will fit the bill but I am looking something for beginners and the cheapest way to fly myself.

Second Scenario: Suppose only using the basic maintenance, without anything more than an oil/filter etc., which plane would last the longest. Obviously simpler plans require less money per nautical mile; of those which would last the longest?

Comment: I think this question is way too broad, and will be heavily dependent on opinions.  There are plenty of online discussions out there on choosing a GA light piston aircraft, this isn't the place to rehash the subject.  Voting to close.

Comment: Airplanes don't measure their use in miles (for a lot of reasons which flight training should make clear), but in engine & airframe hours - that is, the "Hobbs" meter: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobbs_meter

Comment: A basic plane is more reliable than a more complex plane. A small 4-cylinder engine is more reliable that a larger engine. For thoese reasons I tend to think that a basic, all-metal plane like a C150 or even Cherokee 140 is safe bet (though the 140 has a larger engine).  If you are normally always VFR with light winds an old tailwheel like a Cessna 120/140 or Champ/Chief could work.  Planes of that era may not have the range you want though.  The trip will pe painfully slow with every option I've listed, too.

Comment: @acpilot This is a good answer I would also upvote. I have to come home on the week ends and I would rather fly that trip than drive it. Of the plains you listed which will cost less to keep?

Comment: @acpilot A complex plane can be way more reliable than a basic plane. The A350XWB can probably do over 100 million miles, between its carbon fuselage, well-proven systems, and high availability (the 787 was a bit more experimental, so might not hit the sweet spot). And across the fleet it will take billions of miles between accidents. Nothing GA will ever come close.

Comment: It goes without saying that we are scoping for GA.  Sure, a brand new airliner serviced by a staff of professional mechanics with a practically unlimited budget might have a higher dispatch reliability than a 1946 Aeronca Chief with a 2400hr C-65.

Comment: @Justintimeforfun - they're all cheap to operate. I think a C150 works best. All metal, everyone knows how to maintain an O-200, almost every single A&P has some level of familiarity with Cessnas, parts are everywhere, etc. The fabric planes need new fabric every 20 or so years. Tailwheels might cost a little more to insure. The C150 is just about as basic as it gets while retaining just enough "extra" to be practical...just barely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most reliable aircraft is the one that is maintained the best, and the simpler an aircraft is, the easier it will be for you to afford to maintain it properly—both because it will need less maintenance in the first place and because it'll be cheaper to buy, insure and fuel, leaving more of your funds available for maintenance.

However, the premise of flying to/from a flight school seems fundamentally flawed. You are almost certainly going to need to store your plane at an airport, and if so, you should get instruction *at that airport* rather than fly somewhere else for it. You won't be allowed to fly any significant distance (i.e. enough to justify flying rather than driving) alone anyway with just a student pilot license.

Comment: The flight school has aircraft student parking.

Comment: How far away is your flight school?  Have you been signed off to solo yet?  (You said you were a "beginner"...)  And may we assume you've bounced this plan off your CFI and he/she approves?

Comment: @Justintimeforfun - I think you are missing StephenS’s point. Where will the aircraft be based? Is it your home airport? Or, is it your school airport? You will need parking at both locations. Depending on where you are, one month’s hangar rental alone in one location could cost you anywhere from 2 to 10 full tanks of gas in your car. If you plan on living at home and flying to school every day, it would cost you less to get lessons at your home airport. And, I f you do not have a PPL, a CFI might not endorse your solo flights for commuting purposes. They will be liable.

Comment: On the other hand, if you only plan to make the round-trip flight once a month or even once a week, this would be a fun way to build time. Overnight parking at another location away from school might run $5-20 a night in outdoor tiedown fees. And, your CFI might feel more comfortable endorsing you for an occasional solo flight on a flight by flight basis until you get your PPL. Be aware that the CFI will probably place very stringent requirements on the endorsement (only to listed airports, along listed routes, in almost perfect daytime weather). And, you may still have to drive in some days.

Comment: In the US, a student can't fly solo more than 25nm from their "home" airport without a CFI endorsement *for each flight*. And driving will be faster for anywhere that close

Comment: @DeanF. 390 mile from my house to the school. How much more would it cost compaired to a car? The school has a student runway and parking once a week round trip sound good.

Comment: @StephenS I do plan on getting my private license first before commuting to and from school.

Comment: @Justintimeforfun - Well, just by quick math, more than twice as much. I could drive that trip in 6-7 hours on 1 tank of gas costing me 30-45 dollars a tank depending on fuel costs. I could make that same trip in 4 hours on 40 gallons of fuel in a C172. But, at 4-6 dollars per gallon of avgas, that would total out to 200 dollars per one-way trip for gas alone. You still have to factor in maintenance on the aircraft, oil changes every 25-50 hours, hangar fees away from school, annual inspections, etc. You could reduce the fuel cost to 120 dollars per one-way trip in a SportsCruiser.

Comment: Also remember, any day that you make the one-way commute, you should not have a flight lesson regardless of if you travel by car or by plane. Practice doing an IMSAFE checklist before every commute trip just like you should before every flight. Really, you should be doing a full PAVE and even NWKRAFT before each commute. The A in PAVE can stand for automobile.

Comment: @Dean F.: You could also get a plane with a mogas STC, and pay half as much for gas.

Comment: @Justintimeforfun, i assume that 390 miles is nautical flying miles.  How many statute driving miles, and what kind of speed limit?  To make a fair cost comparison you need to convert to the same unit of measure for distance, then figure time and fuel burn.  As well as other costs, including the value you put on your personal time.  But, if you are serious about pursuing your commercial ticket and would be spending money anyway to drive that far it would be a great way to rack up flight time.

Comment: @MichaelHall you right strait line miles for plane minus wind... Is it worth the extra cost to save an extra few hours a week? I'm not thinking of how to get an engine to run on 87 which many planes can. So fuel is not of concern and parking is not of concern. Now cost of purchasing a plane and up-keep is. Maybe flight time.

Comment: @jamesqf - True. But, after seeing the aftermath of 2 vaporlock crashes linked back to mogas usage, I am leery of using it. At least where I live. One of the schools where I rent has prohibited the use of mogas in their mogas fleet. If you did use mogas, a 6 gallon/hour fuel burn would give you a 50° reduction in fuel cost for a 25-40° decrease in commute time. There is still the costs of ownership to consider. I doubt you could offset that by not owning a car. How would you get to the airport, after all .

Comment: @Justintimeforfun - As Michael Hall has said, if you have the money for aircraft ownership, and just want a way of time-building possibly cheaper than renting, then go for it. Just make sure flying is not your only means of commuting. I like the idea of a SportsCruiser for fuel consumption, speed, and avionics options. I would still use avgas in hot climates, and/or high density altitudes, though. A nice C152 would be cheaper cost of ownership. But, you will sacrifice speed. Considering hours are hours regardless of speed, time-building in a C152 might be worth it.

Comment: @Dean F.: Re cost of ownership, there's a wide range in car cost.  For instance, the Cadillac Escalades that my friend drives (when it's not in the shop, anyway) have a MSRP from =75K -95K, while the really reliable '02 Miata that I drive the most cost me under $5K.  Plenty of decent planes can be had for 70-90K :-)

Answer (score 2):

No plane has these qualities, planes require a lot more servicing than cars both legally and practically. Similarly aircraft parts have service limits and [*heavily* suggested rebuild times](https://www.avweb.com/ownership/the-savvy-aviator-4-debunking-tbo/). Most if not all light aircraft require major servicing (or receive major servicing) at the 2000-2500ish hour mark.

There are comparatively little regulations on car maintenance. Most states require only a yearly inspection that boils down to a visual check of brakes, lights and a few other things as well as an emissions test mostly to keep the DEP happy.

Aircraft on the other hand require a [verbose yearly "annual" inspection](https://www.aopa.org/go-fly/aircraft-and-ownership/maintenance-and-inspections/aircraft-inspections) that can take days for a mechanic to complete. On top of that aircraft equipment needs to be routinely tested and checked for it to be legal for certain types of operation. On the contrary no one ever checks your cars speedometer or tach for proper operation.

Broadly speaking aircraft are also grounded if just about anything is not working where as most people often operate their car with small (or even large) issues. If you ever had an engine knocking issue in an aircraft you would be on the ground as fast as practically possible where as I know people that have driven cars thousands of miles with an "engine knock".

Airplanes also change substantially less than cars so small iterative fixes become difficult. If Toyota finds an issue in the 98 Corolla they can easily fix it in the 99 version. Fixing an airplane can require a lot of paper work, or if its a large issue an mandatory AD may be issued and everyone will be *forced* to fix it while 98 Corollas may still be out with their issues to this day.

---

If you just want a straight answer... A [Piper Archer](https://www.piper.com/model/archer-lx/) or a [Cessna 172](https://cessna.txtav.com/en/piston/cessna-skyhawk) (let the internet debates begin...)

Comment: Actually, most states don't require ANY inspection, other than emissions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_inspection_in_the_United_States#Jurisdictions_requiring_periodic_vehicle_safety_inspections

Comment: @jamesqf i can only speak to the states I have lived in which have all required a minimum safety inspection but that is interesting.

Comment: I have an A&P friend/ co-owner who can sign of on the plane. I can park it in a field or on a lake at home. There must be a set upt that cost less than a car to fly to school then work in the long-run.

Comment: @Justintimeforfun: That's very much going to depend on the car you drive.  At a cruise setting, my Cherokee gets around 18 mpg.  IF you drive a large pickup or SUV, you can probably better this, more so if the route you drive is winding.  Not so if you drive a car that gets decent mpg.  Likewise, you can buy an older Cherokee or 172 for less that many upscale pickups & SUVS.  (And judging from a friend's experience with multiple Escalades, you might pay much less in maintenance :-))  Even better if you do have a realistic way to park the plane at home, or even at a small field near home.

Comment: @Justintimeforfun - What Jamesqf  says is exactly right about it depending on the car and plane compared. A Chevy and a Cadillac will have different costs for the same repair. Even if you do the repair yourself. Although, it is perfectly legal to save money by doing the repair yourself. And, you can get it done the same day. Not much you can do with a certificated aircraft. The OP is comparing a ‘98 Toyota Corolla. Hopefully, he can make repairs himself. Plus, hopefully, he is getting better than 20 mpg (highway) with the car. The plane should be a luxury. Not as your sole means of commuting.

Comment: Just because your buddy signs off on the work, **still has to do the work**. No there does not “must” be a way.  Aircraft are more expensive to own and maintenance is much more frequent and more expensive.  You might as well say “there must be a way to drive a Ferrari and get better MPG than my Corolla” - you can say it, but there isn’t.

Comment: @Harper - Reinstate Monica: It is definitely not the case that an airplane is ALWAYS more expensive. I spend less on the Cherokee - both purchase & maintenance - than a good many people spend on their cars.  (Though I also spend a lot less on my cars than they do.)  If you're a competent mechanic, you can also do much of the work yourself, under the supervision of an A&P.  For instance, I do all the time-consuming removal of access covers and so on, so my A&P just has to do the actual inspection.

Comment: @jamesqf this give me hope because I really donnot want to drive 15+ hours a week to school. Yes, I could just stay there, but I have a family. I really need something reliable, not to slow, and easy to fix/keep. Any ideas or concurrence?

Comment: @Justintimeforfun: I couldn't make any recommendations without knowing a lot more about your specific circumstances.  But I'd suggest looking at Trade-A-Plane to get an idea of current prices, consider the value of time-building to you, objectively judge your ability to maintain a plane, and so on.

Comment: @jamesqf It is really simple and maybe I should edit my post to reflect it. I need the cheapest plane I can build time on. The plane does not have to go 400 miles on a tank as long as I can land to refuel on the way.